# Migrate java apps (Azure function apps) to runtime 3.x from 2.x for GRADLE

Tags: java, gradle, azure-functions

microsoft has documentation to update your pom.xml to migrate from runtime 2.x to 3.x:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions

However, I have a java/gradle project and I'm assuming I would need to update something in the build.gradle.... any idea how to do this?

There's supposed to be a property called FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION with a  that can be set when doing it for the pom.xml, is it similiar for the build.gradle?

Comment: Find a tutorial: [Azure-Functions-Gradle-Plugin](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/wiki/Azure-Functions-Gradle-Plugin-(Preview)). Please have a check with my answer. If it helps, please mark it as answer which may help others further. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the [Azure Functions Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/wiki/Azure-Functions-Gradle-Plugin-(Preview)) is in preview version.

By checking the v3 pom file, I see that `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` is added as an app setting:

[image]

So, based on the official tutorial: [add build.gradle and settings.gradle to your azure function project](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/wiki/Azure-Functions-Gradle-Plugin-(Preview)#step-2-add-buildgradle-and-settingsgradle-to-your-azure-function-project)

You just need to add an app setting:

```
azurefunctions {
    subscription = <your subscription ID>
    resourceGroup = 'java-functions-group'
    appName = 'fabrikam-functions-20191216104001380-01'
    pricingTier = 'Consumption'
    region = 'westus'
    runtime {
      os = 'windows'
    }
    appSettings {
        FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION = '~3'
    }

    authentication {
        type = 'azure_cli' 
    }
    localDebug = "transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"
    deployment {
        type = 'run_from_blob'
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I added the appSettings property to my build.gradle but it looks like I was still getting this error " Could not find method appSettings() for arguments [build_4uc6nd2k5o3jtxwlupu6m9lb5$_run_closure15@1b028715] on root project 'edge_bootstrap_ms' of type org.gradle.api.Project." Does this property have to be nested inside somewhere in the build.gradle?

Comment: Also , this only effects local runs of the azure func apps correct?